# How does wearing a bra affect the firmness of breasts?

Tags: breast

I have been looking around for some time now trying to understand how the usage of a bra affects the firmness of breasts. Some people say that it is fundamental to prevent it from becoming flaccid, others even say that making the breasts "weightless" has a negative impact on their solidity.

Since this should be a matter of some interest if nothing else to women interested in the appearance of their brests, I was wondering if anybody did a thorough research on this. It should also be quite easy to study the firmness of breasts in relation to the attitude to wear a bra.

Comment: "It should also be quite easy to study" - that strikes me as highly unlikely. Breast firmness certainly changes with age, and bra wearing attitudes change with cultural trends, so will correlate somewhat with birth years. Bra types also changed a lot over the past decades. You need longitudinal data for very long periods of time, with age matched controls (expensive, high loss of subjects), a standardized measure of "firmness" which must have stayed unchanged for decades, and a sureness that subjects don't deviate from their condition over a lifetime. The topic is not a high (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) priority in public health either, so unlikely to have been run as public research, while privately funded research of this timescale is very unusual, and probably biased. So, while I am not *certain* that no good study exist about the subject, I'd say it's a very difficult subject to study, not an easy one as you claim.

Answer (score 1):

Bras can negatively impact your breast.

[Medical News Today](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/259073.php)

- Based on:

> Jean-Denis Rouillon, a sports science expert from the University of
>   Besançon, France, reported after a 15-year study.

- > women who never wore bras had nipples on average seven millimeters
  >   higher in relation to their shoulders each year
- Do nothing for back pain and weaken muscles
- Make breast saggier due to muscle weakening and some say affect breathing

Bras can immobolize breast stopping them from moving and can be to tight and hold them in unnatural positions this causing negative effects.

But varying on your weight, cup, age and other factors no bra may not be for you.

[Poor Bra Choice Could Be Damaging Breasts Of Some Women](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/releases/116240.php)

Comment: See: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/45985/43717 about the 15-year study. At the time of the Medical News Today report, Rouillon was in the early stages of his study and hadn't studied the issue for 15 years at that point